# SQL: Change SQL table with start and end XY

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm trying to manipulate an SQL table from the database Vertica.

Each row of the table has a start and end XY coordinates (which draws a subpath). Each subpaths when drawn in a map joins together to form a path (denoted by the unique route name). That is why the EndX, End Y is the same as the StartX, StartY for each route.

As the mapping software can only read only X & Y columns only, hence I need to squeeze them into just two columns.

To spare the details (think I did not explain well enough), I have a sample illustration below, on how the table looks like, and what it should become.

[image]

Provided a better raw data below for anyone who can help out to do a sample SQL statement. Thank you in advance!

**Original Table**

```
RouteName,Sequence,StartX,StartY,EndX,EndY
road a,1,1.2323,23.1231,1.3242,23.54354
road a,2,1.3242,23.5435,1.3342,24.23533
road b,1,1.4312,25.3432,1.4454,25.2322
road b,2,1.4454,25.2322,1.4634,25.3424
road b,3,1.4634,25.3424,1.5213,26.2132
```

**Final Table**

```
RouteName,Sequence,X,Y
road a,1,1.2323,23.1231
road a,2,1.3242,23.5435
road a,3,1.3342,24.23533
road b,1,1.4312,25.3432
road b,2,1.4454,25.2322
road b,3,1.4634,25.3424
road b,4,1.5213,26.2132
```

UPDATE: the final output will be used for drawing a route path in Tableau~ Each route is defined by the XY, and the line will follow the Sequence number.

Comment: If it weren't for the sequence numbers you could just do a `UNION` between the starting and ending x and y coordinates.

Comment: what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Assuming an AI PK, could that still work using the ascending order of the PK as the sequence order?

Comment: @Pirate the final output will be used for drawing a route path in Tableau~ Each route is defined by the line which follow the Sequence number and XY coordinates.

Comment: @Strawberry Believe it or not your edit to text actually makes it harder to read in this case :-(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't believe it - but if you want to roll back, I can't really stop you - anyway, looks like you've got this one covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised that some of my sequences have breaks, in that case this script should work better. More concise too I thought

```
select routename,sequence,startx,starty
from table

union all

select routename, max(sequence)+1 as sequence, endx as startx, endy as starty
from table
group by routename

order by routename
```

Comment: You shouldn't give an answer which doesn't match your original question.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't it match? the result is exactly the same :/ Do pardon me as my sql is obviously not as good.

Answer (score 3):

Appreciate that your problem appears to distill down to adding the `n + 1` ordered pair for each route.  One approach is then to simply `UNION` together every starting point with a second query which identifies the end point.

```
SELECT RouteName,
       Sequence,
       StartX,
       StartY
FROM yourTable
UNION
(
    SELECT t1.RouteName,
           t1.Sequence + 1,
           t1.EndX,
           t1.EndY
    FROM yourTable t1
    LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t1.EndX = t2.StartX AND
           t1.EndY = t2.StartY AND
           t1.RouteName = t2.RouteName
    WHERE t2.RouteName IS NULL
)
```

I didn't order the result set, but the tricky part here is coming up with the query, and hopefully this has you covered.